# Interface for not instantiated classes

Tags: typescript

I have code structure like this:

```
interface ITool {
  repair(): void;
}

type HandlersMap = Map<string, ITool>;

abstract class AbstractTool {

  constructor(protected qpr, protected ctx) { }

  abstract async repair(): Promise<void>
}

class DebugTool extends AbstractTool implements ITool {
  async repair(): Promise<void> {
    this.logger.info(`Repaired item: ${this.qpr.type}`);
  }
}

class ToolFactory {
  private handlersMap: HandlersMap = new Map([
    ['debug-message', DebugTool]
  ]);

  createTool(type: string): ITool {
    ...
  }
}
```

Which results in error:

> handlersMap: Property 'repair' is missing in type 'typeof DebugTool' but
>   required in type 'ITool'.

I know it's because i have not instantiated class as a value of Map, but in still implement interface that i refer to. What is the problem and which interface should i use for the value of the Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of:

```
type HandlersMap = Map<string, { new(...args): ITool }>;
```

If you know more about the constructor args, you can be more specific (e.g. if all tools have the arguments `qpr` and `ctx` you can use that instead of the variadic `...args`).

Comment: Great answer. Any info on why it should be like `new (...args) => ITool`. Would be awesome, because syntax for me a bit confusing, even though i think i got the point ?

Comment: That is the type for a constructor function, which is essentially what classes are in JavaScript. So you if you want to refer to a class rather than to an instance of it, you need this kind of type which says "this thing can be new'd".